# Is this datasheet wrong?

Tags: transistors, bjt, datasheet, symbol

http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/395/DTA124%20EE%20A12-248319.pdf

It says it is a PNP transistor but symbol is of NPN transistor. The equivalent circuit shows the transistor sitting between load and ground which is how NPN is typically used.

Comment: looks messed up to me...

Comment: DTA124 is a PNP device. https://eu.mouser.com/Search/Refine.aspx?Keyword=DTA124

Comment: Don't buy that.

Comment: maybe they use a different symbol for PNP transistors!

Comment: It is also described as a diode!

Comment: Someone no speaky da gud English me thinks, but with a Japanese accent.

Comment: @ThePhoton oh.. I was remembering it as Toshiba... oops

Comment: They have copied one or more other data sheets to make this one and have done so poorly. The overall content MAY be OK but no figure can be trusted. || When examining Asian (particularly but not only) datasheets of suspect products I often find a text string that looks liable to be unique and web-search for it. oNE CAN OFTEN TURN UP THE ORIGINAL PLUS OFTEN A NUMBER OF OTHER COPIES.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The DTA124 is a PNP transistor originally [made by Rohm](http://www.rohm.com/web/eu/products/-/product/DTA124EM), and [Rohm's datasheet](http://www.rohm.com/web/eu/datasheet/DTA124EM/dta124emt2l-e) is consistent.

Taiwan Semiconductor intends its DTA124 to be clone of that, so it must be a PNP, too. There are lots of similar DTA/DTC datasheets for all the resistor combinations, so it is *somewhat* understandable (but not excusable) that these copy/paste errors can slip through QC (especially if you have to cut costs to be profitable at cloning).

---

As for the ground: Taiwan Semiconductor copied some NPN circuit image, and left out the complete explanation of the PNP signals:

[image: DTA124 internal circuit]

Here, the ground is the most *positive* part of the circuit. And since the emitter is the fixed voltage against which the other voltage levels are measured, it is technically correct to call it "ground".

Comment: The Taiwan Semi datasheet didn't copy this diagram correctly. The Taiwan Semi datasheet shows the emitter arrow pointing away from the base.

Comment: Sorry; I was focused on the ground issue.

Answer (score 7):

Something in the datasheet is wrong. The question is what.

I'm inclined to think it's most likely the symbol, and the device is actually a PNP type. The reason is that the Vcc, "input" and "output" voltages are specified with negative values.

But it would be wise to get a sample and do some checking with a multimeter before committing to the part. I also don't see any drawing showing which physical pin is which, so that's another thing to check.

Comment: POP type, lol. I used to have a lot of trouble with those!

Comment: Don't they all go POP if you don't use them right?

Comment: Autocorrect knows the truth once again.